# spring integration dynamic filter based on the current Date

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to use ftp-inbound-adapter to poll files based on the the current date.And my inbound adapter uses a filter which refers to bean myfilter .The problem here is the current date is initailized at the startup and is not been processed dynamically..I would like to get the current date for every new message

```
    <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
                    channel="ftpChannel"
                    session-factory="ftpsClientFactory"
                    filter="myFilter"
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg value="#{T(java.time.LocalDateTime).now().format(T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('MMddyy'))}.(xls|xlsx)"/>
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
        </bean>
```

UPDATE

I changed from this

```
    <bean id="currentDate" class="java.util.Date" factory-bean="fastDateFormat"
        scope="prototype" factory-method="format" >
        <aop:scoped-proxy/> 
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="java.util.Date" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


<bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg value="#{currentDate}.(xls|xlsx)"/>
        </bean>
```

And my inbound adapter uses a filter which refers to bean myFilter .. The problem here is the current date is initailized at the startup and is not been processed dynamically..I would like to get the current date for every new message

Comment: change your filter bean to 'prototype' as well

Comment: @AhsanShah: I tried that..It isnt working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This impossible with your current configuration because that `filter` is just a `singleton` bean created only once at start up pulling that your `currentDate` for injection only once as well.

You may try to add `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` into your `currentDate` bean definition, though: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection, but I would suggest to inject `BeanFactorty` into your `filter` and call `getBean("currentDate", Date.class)` every time you need a new instance of that prototype.

**UPDATE**

You inject `BeanFactory` into your `filter` instead of that `currentDate` bean. And then when filter logic is called you do `Date currentDate = this.beanFactory.getBean("currentDate", Date.class);`.

**UPDATE2**

Here is what I think should work for you:

```
public class DynamicRegexPatternFilter extends AbstractFileListFilter<File> {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return Pattern.compile(this.beanFactory.getBean("currentDate", String.class) + ".(xls|xlsx)")
                .matcher(file.getName())
                .matches();
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to add <aop:scoped-proxy/> into my currentDate bean.. Its still loading date at the start up . What would be the other option apart from the current configuration that i am using?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer, please.

Comment: Show your filter code and I’ll modify it respectively

Comment: Please, edit your question with proper code formatting. It's not readable in the comments

Comment: I don't see any `currentDate` bean reference in your `myFilter` bean definition. Also I asked you to place `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` for the `currentDate`, not `filter` bean. Also the `prototype` is not going to work for the `filter` bean. It is indeed going to be instantiated only once for that `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter`. you definitely need a custom `FileListFilter` for such a custom logic.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: No, that `<constructor-arg value="#{currentDate}.(xls|xlsx)"/>` still not going to work. You resolve a bean really only once at start up. That expression is not evaluated every time. As I said: you need a custom `FileListFilter` to build a pattern in Java code for every incoming file.

Comment: <bean id="myFilter" class="package.FileNamePattern" scope="prototype">
</bean> And the custom class has something like     public class FileNamePattern {

 @Autowired
 BeanFactory beanFactory;

 public FileNamePattern() {

  Date date=this.beanFactory.getBean("currentDate", Date.class);

 }

}

Comment: Sounds much better!

Comment: :But how is this date mapped back to myFilter. And how can we use this date value  back in our filter? .. I am not able to follow on the link part..How these things work in the background

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE2 in my answer.

Comment: <bean id="myFilter" class="package.DynamicRegexPatternFilter" scope="prototype">
    </bean>
 
 <bean id="fastDateFormat" class="org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat"
  scope="prototype" factory-method="getInstance">
  <constructor-arg value="MMddyy" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="currentDate" class="java.util.Date" factory-bean="fastDateFormat"
  scope="prototype" factory-method="format" > 
  <constructor-arg>
   <bean class="java.util.Date" scope="prototype"/>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

Comment: I think you can't change system date for already ran JVM. That's already out of scope of our current problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom filter. Implement FileListFilter and override filterFiles method which takes input argument as array of LsEntry. LsEntry is nothing but a small metadata object of a File present at (S)FTP. It comprises of File Name and the date on which it was modified.

```
@Override
public List<LsEntry> filterFiles(LsEntry[] files) {
    List<LsEntry> result = new ArrayList<LsEntry>();
    Vector<LsEntry> list = new Vector<LsEntry>();
    Collections.addAll(list, files);
    ChannelSftp.LsEntry lastModifiedEntry = Collections.max(list,
            (Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getAttrs().getMTime())));
    result.add(lastModifiedEntry);
    return result;
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60635859/11325128