# fetching files from SFTP

Tags: java, sftp, ssh2-sftp, j2ssh

I want to fetch files from SFTP which are created after a given timestamp(time of last pull) in java. I am using j2ssh as of now. Please let me know if some other API supports such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Jsch supports the ls command which will bring you back all the attributes of the remote file.  You can write a little code to eliminate the files you want to retrieve from there.

Java Doc: http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/

This example compares the remote file timestamps to find the oldest file, it wouldn't be much of a stretch to modify it to compare your last run date against the remote file date, then do the download as part of the loop.

Code from [Finding file size and last modified of SFTP file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641286/finding-file-size-and-last-modified-of-sftp-file-using-java)

```
try {
    list = Main.chanSftp.ls("*.xml");
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        fileFound = false;
    }
    else {
        lsEntry = (ChannelSftp.LsEntry) list.firstElement();
        oldestFile = lsEntry.getFilename();
        attrs = lsEntry.getAttrs();
        currentOldestTime = attrs.getMTime();
        for (Object sftpFile : list) {
            lsEntry = (ChannelSftp.LsEntry) sftpFile;
            nextName = lsEntry.getFilename();
            attrs = lsEntry.getAttrs();
            nextTime = attrs.getMTime();
            if (nextTime < currentOldestTime) {
                oldestFile = nextName;
                currentOldestTime = nextTime;
            }
        }
```